# Error While Deploying wsp in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, dll, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I am upgrading an SP2007 project to SP2010 where I have made the necessary changes to the project(changed the reference, master pages, etc.). I have deployed the farm solution in my machine I am getting the following error:

> Cannot add the specified assembly to the global assembly cache: System.Web.Extensions.dll.

I have referenced this DLL in my project.

Could anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: this happens sometimes, dll has lock by some process, the fast way to avoid this - reboot your machine

Answer (score 3):

Another good idea is to include an iisreset and a Restart-Timer SPtimerv4 while deploying, as this will help to release similar locks.
However, do you really need to deploy System.Web.Extensions with your WSP now that you've upgraded to 2010? Since 2010 runs on .Net framework 3.5 it should already be present on your server..

Best regards,
Rikard